# Django : 'Form' object has no attribute 'clean_data'

Tags: python, django, forms, web

I made password reset form which takes 3 passwords, old password, new password, and confirm for new password. So far I succeeded to make it displayed in the html but couldn't proceed further. whenever I click submit button it displays error message. I've been search about this errors in stack overflow and changed it but still keep displaying error.

This is the error message.

```
AttributeError at /blog/password_change/blue/
'PasswordChangeForm' object has no attribute 'clean_data'
```

View.py

```
@login_required
def password_change(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():            
            oldpassword = form.cleaned_data.get('oldpassword')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            password2 = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if oldpassword == password2:
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.username)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/password_change_done/') 
        else:
            return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'error_message': 'password mismatch'})
            #return redirect(reverse('blog:home'))
            #return redirect(reverse('blog:profile', args=[form.user.get_username()]))

else:
    print("C")
    form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
    return redirect(reverse('blog:profile', args=[form.user.get_username()]))
```

for oldpassword = form.cleaned_data.get('oldpassword'), I also tried  oldpassword = form.Cleaned_data['oldpassword'] too but it made same error message.

forms.py

```
class PasswordChangeForm(forms.Form):
oldpassword = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput())
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput())
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput())

def __init__(self, user, data, **kwargs):
    self.user = user
    super(PasswordChangeForm, self).__init__(data, **kwargs)

def clean_oldpassword(self):
    if self.clean_data.get('oldpassword') and not self.user.check_password(self.clean_data['oldpassword']):
        raise ValidationError('Please type your current password.')
    return self.clean_data['oldpassword']

def clean_password2(self):
    if self.clean_data.get('password1') and self.clean_data.get('password2') and self.clean_data['password1'] != self.clean_data['password2']:
        raise ValidationError('The new passwords are not the same')
    return self.clean_data['password2']
```

Comment: shouldn't it be cleaned_data ?

Comment: @Darshan Yes.. thanks for let me know. I changed it.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: @Darshan Actually It starts to create different error message. It says ''QueryDict' object has no attribute 'check_password''.

Comment: try printing your user object

Comment: here is issue form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)  , instead of user=request.POST it should user=request.user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code had multiple issue,

1) instead of `clean_data` it should be `cleaned_data`

2) While passing user object in form you should set `user=request.user` not `user=request.POST`:

```
form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
```